# Como imprimir um texto (cupom) via javascript?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, impressão

Tenho uma aplicação web comercial escrita em ASP.NET MVC4 com c#, onde preciso imprimir um cupom de fechamento de venda direto para uma impressora não-fiscal (diebold).

Existe alguma forma de enviar, que seja por JS, um documento direto para a impressora, sem visualizar impressão ou confirmar nada?

Como se eu montasse uma string no JS, ou recebesse via AJAX e a imprimisse!

Comment: Não​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @bfavaretto se puder especificar o que exatamente não é possível, talvez eu adapte o requisito para tornar a ideia viável! O problema esta em imprimir via JS ou em não mostrar o dialogo de impressão?

Comment: O JS que roda no browser é propositalmente limitado, por questões de segurança. Não dá nem para imprimir sem a caixa de diálogo, nem para se comunicar diretamente com a impressora. Como diz o Renan na resposta abaixo, no caso do IE pode ser possível burlar isso, com as configurações certas de segurança e provavelmente o uso de algum controle ActiveX ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for para pular as telas de visualização e confirmação, não dá pra ser cross-browser. Isso é da implementação navegador. **Talvez** seja possível com o IE, se você configurar uma impressora como padrão - embora eu não conheça o IE a fundo e não possa garantir que isso seja mesmo possível - mas garanto que no Chrome não dá porque ele vai necessariamente mostrar ao menos o diálogo onde você escolhe se quer mandar para um dispositivo ou salvar como documento.

**Edição:** O Chrome tem um modo quiósque, [vide a resposta do Vitor Pinho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216222/1658). No entanto, o modo quiósque tem lá seus problemas. Essa solução já parou de funcionar de uma versão para outra antes, então caso deseje utilizá-la, talvez você precise congelar a versão do navegador em seu POS.

O próprio Javascript é construído com isso em mente. Para pedir uma impressão com JS, você chama o método `print` do objeto `window`. Assim:

```
window.print();
```

Em termos bem básicos... Isso é uma forma de você dizer pro navegador: *"faça de conta que o usuário apertou CTRL+P na janela onde este script é executado!"* Daí pra frente o código de impressão executado é **o do navegador e não o seu**.

Fora isso, é considerada boa prática você ter uma folha de estilo (CSS) de impressão, que é distinta da folha "principal" do site. Essa folha de estilo de impressão normalmente remove cores e imagens de fundo, cabeçalhos, rodapés etc. para deixar o conteúdo mais apropriado para impressão. Quando for imprimir, não chame `window.print();` na janela do conteúdo: abra uma nova aba com o conteúdo ***E*** a folha de estilo de impressão, e nessa nova aba chame `window.print();`. Boa sorte!

Comment: Entendi, e teria alguma alternativa a isso? Visto que a demanda por aplicações web tem crescido consideravelmente.

Comment: @PedroRamon permita-me repetir a resposta do bfavaretto: **não**. Se isso é um requisito tão forte, talvez você precise de um **aplicativo**, não de uma aplicação ;)

Comment: Obrigado @Renan.. caso eu escreva um aplicativo para realizar esta operação, e o instale no cliente, sabe me dizer se consigo comunicar minha pagina com este aplicativo?

Comment: Não vejo porque não.

Answer (score 2):

Você consegue no Chrome, iniciando o navegador no modo kiosk:

1. Cria um atalho do Chrome
2. Clica com o botão direito no atalho e seleciona a opção propriedades
3. No field "Destino" adicione ao final (após as aspas) o seguinte comando : **--kiosk-printing**
4. Feche todas as instâncias do Chrome e inicialize uma instância pelo atalho criado

Dessa forma ao pedir para imprimir não será aberta a janela de impressão do Chrome e a impressão será enviada para a impressora padrão. Essa inclusive é a limitação, pois só pode ser enviado para a impressora padrão do sistema e não dá para escolher outra.

Comment: Essa solução é correta e tem meu voto positivo, mas tem alguns problemas. Essa opção vive tendo bugs (i.e.: para de funcionar de uma versão para outra, [provoca lag de minutos na impressão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093379/chrome-kiosk-printing-has-1-2-minute-lag-delay)) etc. #YMMV.